# how to change the font size of the terminal

Tags: python, tkinter

Hello this code below opens a terminal inside python GUI, my question is how we could change the font attributes of the opened terminal

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
root = Tk()
termf = Frame(root, height=1300, width=1000)

termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

wid = termf.winfo_id()
os.system('xterm -into %d  -geometry 70x60 -sb & '% wid)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `-fa pattern: FreeType font-selection pattern` option:

```
from Tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
termf = Frame(root, height=1300, width=1000)

termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

wid = termf.winfo_id()
font = "'dejavu serif'"
os.system('xterm -into %d  -geometry 70x60 -sb  -fa -%s- & ' % (wid, font))
root.mainloop()
```